# R- Shiny- SQL- Dropbox: can they work together?

Tags: sql, r, shiny, dropbox

We have a shiny app running from our institute server (basically modifying a table).
We would like to store the table in an SQL DB.
Is it possible to save the SQL DB in a Dropbox account and interact with it from there?

Pseudocode:

- load table from Dropbox SQL db
- create DT data table
- modify the data table in shiny
- Update the SQL DB in Dropbox

I am asking for any working examples illustrating the first and last steps above.
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're referring to by "Dropbox SQL db" - does Dropbox have an own SQL service? I believe not. Do you have some kind of SQL dump in the dropbox?

Anyways, what you could do, is setting up a sqlite database and save it to the dropbox. To my knowledge, SQLite does not support concurrent connections, but if only one user is accessing the SQLite db, then it should work.

Check out [RSQlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html).

/Edit: Of course, the institute server also has to have direct access to the dropbox.

Comment: SQLite concurrency: https://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html and https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/begin-concurrent/doc/begin_concurrent.md, but both of those assume that concurrent users all have access to the same actual file (on the same filesystem); a file that is immediately sync'd across the web does not afford that, so I think the discussion of "SQLite and Concurrency" is relatively moot. However, if the server-end of this has multiple processes that all share the same local filesystem, then it may apply.

Comment: thanks for the additional info on SQLite, it seems I was a little outdated.

Comment: yes and no ... if all processes are on a local drive, that's one thing ... but often it is on a network share, in which case file locking and other mechanisms are not reliable ... so I always assume that I should not rely on concurrency